# Adding custom value to SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT r.record_id,
       r.part_id,
       r.record_dt,
       a.association_part_a,
       a.association_part_b,
       a.association_type,
       a.association_id,
       r.product_id
FROM   dbo.synfact_association AS a
       INNER JOIN dbo.synfact_record AS r
               ON a.record_id = r.record_id
WHERE  ( r.part_id IN (SELECT part_id
                       FROM   dbo.synfact_record AS synfact_record_1
                       WHERE  ( record_status = 1 )
                              AND ( record_type = 0 )) )
       AND ( r.product_id IN ( 38, 39, 40, 41,
                               42, 43, 44, 45,
                               46, 37, 47, 48,
                               49, 50, 51, 52,
                               53, 54, 58, 59 ) )
       AND ( r.record_id > 499 )
       AND ( r.record_status = 1 )
```

I want to use the record_dt of the second query as a replacement of the record_dt in the first query. I want to do that by linking the values on the part_id since they both have it. First query is giving a list of record_id that has part_id, the second query is taking the latest record_dt for each record_id. My end goal is to take the latest record_dt from the second query to replace in the first query. I can link them both on the part_id.

I need to replace the r.record_dt with this SELECT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RECORD_DT FROM synfact_record WHERE PROCESS_STEP_LIST_ID IN (21,22,23) ORDER BY RECORD_DT DESC
```

This is what the first query does

| RECORD_ID | PART_ID | RECORD_DT | ASSOCIATION_PART_A | ASSOCIATION_PART_B | ASSOCIATION_TYPE | ASSOCIATION_ID | PRODUCT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 286660 | SYN12021020100018 | 2021-02-15 11:18:11.840 | SYN12021020100018 | 21-02-01-000003 | unique_id | 452028 | 39 |
| 287146 | SYN12021020300773 | 2021-02-17 07:30:59.603 | SYN12021020300773 | 2102-00-005218 | unique_id | 455735 | 38 |
| 287147 | SYN12021020300774 | 2021-02-17 07:31:04.780 | SYN12021020300774 | 2102-00-005219 | unique_id | 455736 | 38 |

The second query returns:

| RECORD_DT |
| --- |
| 2021-10-20 11:36:02.670 |
| 2021-10-20 11:35:29.263 |
| 2021-10-20 11:34:59.583 |

**I want to replace the record_dt by the one with the second SELECT.**

I know I must append it to the first query, I just don't know how...

Which method is best to do this?

Comment: `r.record_dt` is a scalar value. You can't just replace it with a result set of potentially multiple rows. Provide a **minimal** example with desired results. We don't need any irrelevant joins or where clause predicates in the minimal example

Comment: There you go, I edited everything as you asked. @MartinSmith

Comment: You can't have a separate list of rows for a specific column, that makes no sense, you'd need to amend the logic of the first query, you need to provide some example data for each table and the desired results.

Comment: @Stu I provided the example of data of each query/tables in the links.

Comment: Please don't post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, you cannot cut and paste from an image, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) link.

Comment: @Stu Since I've done everything I was asked for, I'd love to have anything that look like an answer..

Comment: So what's the result of the second query?

Comment: As shown, it's a different record_dt.

Comment: As shown? I don't see where. You show the result of the first query. Also, the second query should return exactly one value, which is another thing we can't see. And also, the second query is independent of the first one. If it returns one value, then why not get that value first and replace `r.record_dt` by that value? Maybe you should show the end result you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @GertArnold There you go, I've added the result for the second query. It returns a list of value. I need to link it on the part_id, but I don't know how to do this since I already have a WHERE clause on the first query

Comment: You still don't seem to understand what others already have been asking: how would you replace one value by three values? Again, which end result do you imagine?

Comment: @GertArnold That's the whole question. I want to use the record_dt of the second query as a replacement of the record_dt in the first query.  I want to do that by linking the values on the part_id since they both have it.

First query is giving a list of record_id that has part_id, the second query is taking the latest record_dt for each record_id.

My end goal is to take the latest record_dt from the second query to replace in the first query. I can link them both on the part_id

Comment: So why not tell that right from the start? We can't guess what your tables and their contents look like.

Comment: I'm still learning, my bad I was a bit too close to the problem. Since you now know the question, any take on how to do it?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. A minimal example with sample data (including DDL), the query, expected results and a description of the problem helps us help you. (A complete [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) example is even better.) A list of 20 values to check `product_id` against doesn't add value to the question. Extraneous columns and conditions are distractions.

Comment: I really don't know what to add to explain the situation... after reading it you really don't understand what I want to do?I understand the extra code, but I need for you to understand that the first query does have a WHERE clause so the answer include that. I really thought the paragraph I added at the beginning was like @GertArnold wanted.

Comment: I still don't get how you actually want to link up these two queries, it's completely unclear. How do we correlate the three values in the second query to the first?

Comment: @Charlieface I want to link them on the PART_ID with an INNER JOIN maybe? The values in the second query are the most recent RECORD_DT. I want them to replace the RECORD_DT that the first query is giving. I know I need to integrate the second query in the first one but I don't understand how to do that

Comment: Sorry I don't see `PART_ID` in the second query. Please correct it

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, I think I'll close this question. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You can LIMIT 1 to your select clause, you can use query like this:

```
SELECT r.record_id,
       r.part_id,
    CASE
        WHEN r.PROCESS_STEP_LIST_ID IN (21 , 22, 23) THEN 
            (SELECT DISTINCT RECORD_DT FROM synfact_record WHERE PROCESS_STEP_LIST_ID IN (21,22,23) ORDER BY RECORD_DT DESC LIMIT 1)
        ELSE r.RECORD_DT
    END as record_dt,
       a.association_part_a,
       a.association_part_b,
       a.association_type,
       a.association_id,
       r.product_id
FROM   dbo.synfact_association AS a
       INNER JOIN dbo.synfact_record AS r
               ON a.record_id = r.record_id
```

Comment: I need that for all rows so it doesn't work that way, I tried it. Thanks though!

Comment: "I need that for all rows so it doesn't work that way, I tried it"....maybe if you could possibly please take the time to show us what you want your end result to like ....it may save us all some time :-)

Comment: @GrahamH I need to replace the current record_dt to the record_dt from the second query that I have written.

Comment: @JoeBackstab - I edited the query to fetch conditionally. Can you check ?

Comment: @VinodhThimmisetty The logic is good, but It returns an error since there's multiple values in the  `SELECT DISTINCT RECORD_DT FROM synfact_record WHERE PROCESS_STEP_LIST_ID IN (21,22,23) ORDER BY RECORD_DT DESC`

Comment: @VinodhThimmisetty Since nobody tried to help me after pointing out what was wrong with my post, I'm choosing you as a solution for helping me. Thanks again and keep up the good work